# Why does the console log an operation that occurs after the statement? JS and DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, compilation

I'm trying to learn how to manipulate the DOM with JS and while messing around I console logged the h1 elements I wanted to change. I noticed that when I console logged the elements it said their innerHTML and textContent was the same value as what I changed it to after the console log statements.

Why does the console log statement reflect future changes I made to the h1 elements?

Here's my JS code

```
var allh1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1")
console.log(allh1); //innerHTML and textContent both listed as "now all h1's are changed here"
for (var i = 0; i < allh1.length; i++) {
  allh1[i].textContent = "Now all h1's are changed"; //I gave them that textContent in this line
}
```

Here's my HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Getting started with jQuery</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                color: rgb(16, 10, 102);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1 id="heading">What is jQuery?</h1>

    <p>jQuery is the most popular JavaScript library. It gives developers lots of useful functions so they can make their webpage interactive across multiple browsers.</p>

    <p class="note">jQuery is an open source library with a big community of contributors.</p>

    <h1>Why should you learn jQuery?</h1>

    <p>If you learn jQuery, you'll be able to use it in your own webpages, understood other developer's webpages, and have a better understanding generally about how to use libraries.</p>

    <p class="note">Note: jQuery functions use the DOM API (like <code>document.getElementById</code>). You should  learn that first, if you haven't yet.</p>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_and_vanilla_js_here.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide your html as well?

Comment: Because you see *active references* to those elements in the console. It doesn't copy their state at the moment of the log, it hands you a reference to the elements.

Comment: @MikeC I'm confused why that's the case. Why wouldn't the active state be what the h1 said at line 5? For example, when I set 2 obj = obj1 in JS and change their properties they change together, but a console log on line 5 won't say the objects state at line 20, it'd just say what the object currently contains

Comment: @Gwater17 I'm not following. As you said, if you have two references to the same object and you modify one, then you'll change "both." Likewise, if you log some objects (or elements) to the console on line 5, change those objects on line 20, then look at them in the console, you'll see the changes you made on line 20.

Comment: You would see the original values if you did JSON.stringify when you logged to console.  Otherwise it's up to the consoleui implementation whether it pulls the values to display when you expand it or when it is logged.

Comment: @algorithmicMoose Tried that but I just got ```{"0":{},"1":{}}```

Comment: @MikeC I was trying to say that if I logged the objects at line 5 I'd see the objects state at line 5 and if Iogged them on line 20 I'd see the objects state at line 20. Whereas, here I'm asking to log the elements when the h1 textContent is supposed to be "Why should you learn jQuery?", but instead its saying the h1 textContent is "Now all h1's are changed". However, I changed the h1 textContent to "Now all h1's are changed" two lines below where I console logged the h1s. Hope that makes sense.